# BigQuery - is there a way to find missing dates in a data sequence?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

We have setup up some GA360 exports directly live to our BigQuery and how it works that for every one days GA360 export we have a table created in the view. So if you have 400 days worth of GA360 data you should have 400 tables.

From looking at these I have noticed that for some of these views the total amount of tables doesn't match up which means that we could be potentially missing some data. Would there be a way to find the tables/dates that we are missing?

I'm running this query - this give us the dataset and table IDs. I have parsed the table IDs into the date format so we easier to see what dates are there and which aren't. Is there a way to find the missing the dates from the results of the query below

```
SELECT 'xxx' as dataset_id, 
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',RIGHT(table_id,8)) as date 
FROM `project.xxx.__TABLES__` where table_id like 'ga_sessions_2%'
```

**Output**

| dataset_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 2022-04-11 |
| 123456 | 2022-04-12 |
| 123456 | 2022-06-01 |
| 123456 | 2022-06-02 |

Is it possible to modify query above so that there's a record for each date that are we missing between 2022-04-12 and 2022-06-01?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below query for missing dates:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS 
SELECT '123456' dataset_id, DATE '2022-04-11' date UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' dataset_id, DATE '2022-04-12' date UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' dataset_id, DATE '2022-06-01' date UNION ALL
SELECT '123456' dataset_id, DATE '2022-06-02' date;

SELECT date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-04-12', '2022-06-01')) date
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT date FROM sample;
```

- [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array)
- [EXCEPT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except)

###### Multiple Dataset Example

```sql
SELECT dataset_id, date FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT dataset_id FROM sample
),UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-04-12', '2022-06-01')) date
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT dataset_id, date FROM sample;
```

Comment: Link to [`GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array) in case OP wants to know more about it.

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya, sure, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there a way to go about this if there are multiple dataset IDs in the table? Would it be possible to find the missing dates by dataset ID?

Comment: @russianmax, I think it's possible. kindly check the updated answer with **Multiple Dataset Example**